# How to use usestate and setstate instead of this.setState using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to implement a DragAndDrop component using react and typescript and i am new to using react redux.

Below is how the DragAndDrop component looks like,

```
class DragAndDrop extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dragging: false,
        }; 
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.drag_counter = 0;
        this.enable_drag_event_listeners();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.disable_drag_event_listeners();
    }

    enable_drag_event_listeners = () => {
        document.addEventListener('dragenter', this.handle_drag_in);
        document.addEventListener('dragleave', this.handle_drag_out);
        document.addEventListener('dragover', this.handle_drag);
        document.addEventListener('drop', this.handle_drop);
    }

    disable_drag_event_listeners = () => {
        document.removeEventListener('dragenter', this.handle_drag_in);
        document.removeEventListener('dragleave', this.handle_drag_out);
        document.removeEventListener('dragover', this.handle_drag);
        document.removeEventListener('drop', this.handle_drop);
    }

    handle_drag = (e) => {
        if (!this.props.loading) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    }

    handle_drag_in = (e) => {
        if (!this.props.loading) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            this.drag_counter++;
            if (e.dataTransfer.files) {
                this.setState({dragging: true});
            }
        }
    }

    handle_drag_out = (e) => {
        if (!this.props.loading) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            this.drag_counter--;
            if (this.drag_counter === 0) {
                this.setState({dragging: false});
            }
        }
    }

    handle_drop = (e) => {
        if (!this.props.loading) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            this.setState({dragging: false});
            if (e.dataTransfer.files && e.dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {
                this.props.handle_drop(e);
                e.dataTransfer.clearData();
                this.drag_counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.dragging &&
                    <div>
                        <div className="drop_zone">
                            <div className="drop_zone_overlay"/>
                            <div className="drop_zone_text">
                            <div>Drop your files here</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

As you see from above code, i have used this.state and this.setState, componentdidmount, componentdidupdate and componentwillunmount.

I want to use react redux usestate, setstate and other things.

How can i change the above code to use usestate and setstate and how do i implement the componentdidmount, componentdidupdate, componentwillunmount hooks.

what i have tried?

```
function DragAndDrop() {
    const [isdragging, setIsDragging] = React.useState(false);
    handle_drag = (e) => {
        if (!this.props.loading) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    }

    handle_drag_in = (e) => {
        if (!this.props.loading) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            this.drag_counter++; //how do i set this with react redux and also this is not a class

            if (e.dataTransfer.files) {
                setIsDragging(true);
            } 
        }
    }

    handle_drag_out = (e) => {
        if (!this.props.loading) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            this.drag_counter--; // how to keep track of this counter
            if (this.drag_counter === 0) {
                setIsDragging(false);
            }  
        }
    }

    handle_drop = (e) => {
        if (!this.props.loading) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            setIsDragging(false);
            if (e.dataTransfer.files && e.dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {
                this.props.handle_drop(e);
                e.dataTransfer.clearData();
                this.drag_counter = 0; //how to keep track of this
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {isdragging &&
                    <div>
                        <div className="drop_zone">
                            <div className="drop_zone_overlay"/>
                            <div className="drop_zone_text">
                                <div>Drop files here</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Could someone help me with this. thanks. how to consider componentdidmount, componentdidupdate,componentwillunmount in react redux.

thanks.

Comment: you can't use `this` in functional component

Comment: I think you should read https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html first

Comment: okay so how can i modify this component to be used with react and typescript and redux. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const DragAndDrop: React.FC<any> = (props) => {
  const [dragging, setDragging] = React.useState(false);
  const [drag_counter, setDrag_counter] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // componentDidMount()
    setDrag_counter(0);
    enable_drag_event_listeners();
    return () => {
      // componentWillUnmount()
      disable_drag_event_listeners();
    }
  }, []);

  function enable_drag_event_listeners() {
    document.addEventListener('dragenter', handle_drag_in);
    document.addEventListener('dragleave', handle_drag_out);
    document.addEventListener('dragover', handle_drag);
    document.addEventListener('drop', handle_drop);
  }

  function disable_drag_event_listeners() {
    document.removeEventListener('dragenter', handle_drag_in);
    document.removeEventListener('dragleave', handle_drag_out);
    document.removeEventListener('dragover', handle_drag);
    document.removeEventListener('drop', handle_drop);
  }

  function handle_drag(e) {
    if (!props.loading) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  }

  function handle_drag_in(e) {
    if (!props.loading) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      setDrag_counter((prev)=>prev+1);
      if (e.dataTransfer.files) {
        setDragging(true);
      }
    }
  }

  function handle_drag_out(e) {
    if (!props.loading) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      setDrag_counter((prev)=>prev-1);
      if (drag_counter === 0) {
        setDragging(false);
      }
    }
  }

  function handle_drop(e) {
    if (!props.loading) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      setDragging(false);
      if (e.dataTransfer.files && e.dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {
        props.handle_drop(e);
        e.dataTransfer.clearData();
        setDrag_counter(0);
      }
    }
  }
  return ( 
    <div>
    {dragging &&
      <div>
      <div className = "drop_zone" >
        <div className = "drop_zone_overlay" / >
        <div className = "drop_zone_text" >
          <div> Drop your files here </div> 
        </div> 
      </div>
    } 
    {
      props.children
    } 
    </div>
  )

}
```

Comment: i get the error in the place where the enable and disable_drag_event_listeners are defined  like below

"the enable_drag_event_listeners function makes the dependencies of useEffect hook change on every render. move it inside the useEffect callback.
alternatively, wrap the enable_drag_event_listeners into its own useCallback hook"